# Windows Deployment Services without a domain?

Tags: networking, wds

I was wondering if it is possible to use Windows Deployment Services w/o domain access
The reasons why I'm not using setting up a domain (or using an existing one) are irrelevant.

I was wondering if anyone could hint me what steps should I look for in order to setup WDS w/o AD DS ?

Answer (score 7):

This functionality has been added in Windows Server 2008 R2:

Source from: http://www.deployvista.com/Default.aspx?tabid=36&EntryID=129

> In Windows Server 2008 R2, Microsoft
>   added support for using the PXE
>   listener without Active Directory.
>   Here is a complete guide on how to
>   configure a standalone Windows Server
>   2008 R2 WDS Server
>
> Pre-Requisites
>
> In these steps I assume you have a
>   server the following configuration
>
> 1. A Windows Server 2008 R2 named WDS01, installed into a workgroup.
> 2. One network card with a fixed IPv4 address (I’m using 192.168.2.215
>      in my lab)
> 3. Two partitions, C: for the Windows Server 2008 R2 operating
>      System, D: for Data
>
> I also assume you have a DNS Server
>   somewhere in the environment, maybe
>   your local router if it’s a smaller
>   network. In my lab my DNS server /
>   Router has IP address 192.168.2.1. The
>   router has DHCP server disabled.
>
> High level steps:
>
> 1. Download and install Windows AIK 2.0
> 2. Install DHCP and create a scope for the network
> 3. Add the WDS transport role service
> 4. Create and share the RemoteInstall folder structure
> 5. Copy the x86 and x64 boot files
> 6. Copy the x86 and x64 boot images
> 7. Configure the WDS Providers
> 8. Configure the Policies
> 9. Additional DHCP and WDS provider configuration
>
> Download and install Windows AIK 2.0
>
> 1. On WDS01, logon as Administrator.
> 2. Download and Install Windows AIK 2.0 (named Windows AIK for Windows 7 on Microsoft downloads) with the
>      default settings.
>
> Install DHCP and create a scope for
>   the network
>
> 1. On WDS01, using Server Manager, select Roles, and the select Add
>      Roles.
> 2. On the Before You Begin page, select the Skip this page by default
>      checkbox, and click Next.
> 3. In the Select Server Roles list, select DHCP Server and click Next.
> 4. On the DCHP Server page, click Next.
> 5. On the Select Network Connection Bindings page, accept the default
>      settings and click Next.
> 6. On the Specify IPv4 DNS Server Settings page, in the parent domain:
>      textbox, type in whatever DNS Suffix
>      you want to use, I used tslab.net, and
>      click Next.
> 7. On the Specify IPv4 WINS Server Settings page, accept the default
>      settings and click Next.
> 8. On the Add or Edit DHCP Scopes page, click Add. Use the following
>      settings.
>
>    Scope Name: 192.168.2.0/24
>
>    Starting IP address: 192.168.2.100
>
>    Ending IP address: 192.168.2.199
>
>    Subnet Type: Wired (lease duration will be 8 days)
>
>    Activate this scope: Selected
>
>    Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
>
>    Default Gateway (optional): 192.168.2.1
>
>    Click OK, and then click Next.
> 9. On the Configure DHCPv6 Stateless Mode page, accept the
>      default settings and click Next.
>
>    10. On the Specify IPv6 DNS Server Settings page, in the parent domain:
>          textbox, type in whatever DNS Suffix
>          you want to use, I used tslab.net, and
>          click Next.
>    11. On the Confirm Installation Selections page, click Install.
>    12. On the Installation Results page, click Close.
>
> Add the WDS Transport server role
>
> 1. On WDS01, using Server Manager, select Roles, and the select Add
>      Roles.
> 2. In the Select Server Roles list, select Windows Deployment Services and
>      click Next.
> 3. On the Overview of Windows Deployment Services page, click Next.
> 4. On the Select Role Services page, clear the Windows Deployment
>      Service checkbox so that only
>      Transport Server role service is
>      selected, and click Next.
> 5. On the Confirm Installation Selections page, click Install.
> 6. On the Installation Results page, click Close.
>
> Create and share the RemoteInstall
>   folder structure
>
> 1. On WDS01, using Explorer, create the following folder structure:
>
>    D:\RemoteInstall
>
>    D:\RemoteInstall\boot
>
>    D:\RemoteInstall\boot\x86
>
>    D:\RemoteInstall\boot\x86\images
>
>    D:\RemoteInstall\boot\x64
>
>    D:\RemoteInstall\boot\x64\images
> 2. Using Explorer, and the Advanced Sharing feature, share the
>      D:\RemoteInstall folder as REMINST.
>
> Copy the x86 and x64 boot files
>
> 1. On WDS01, using Explorer, create the D:\Mount folder.
> 2. Start a Deployment Tools Command Prompt (found on the start menu, in
>      the All Programs / Microsoft Windows
>      AIK folder), type the following
>      command + press Enter.
>
>    Imagex /mount x86\winpe.wim 1 D:\Mount
> 3. Leave the Deployment Tools Command Prompt open.
> 4. Using Explorer, navigate to the D:\Mount\Windows\boot\PXE folder, copy
>      all content to the
>      D:\RemoteInstall\boot\x86 folder.
> 5. Close all Explorer windows (the wim filter driver in WAIK 2.0 is
>      really sensitive about open file
>      handles when unmounting an image).
> 6. In the Deployment Tools Command Prompt, type the following commands +
>      press Enter after each line.
>
>    Imagex /unmount D:\Mount
>
>    Imagex /mount amd64\winpe.wim 1 D:\Mount
> 7. Using Explorer, navigate to the D:\Mount\Windows\boot\PXE folder,
>      which now contains the x64 boot files,
>      and copy all content to the
>      D:\RemoteInstall\boot\x64 folder.
> 8. Close all Explorer windows.
> 9. In the Deployment Tools Command Prompt, type the following command +
>      press Enter.
>
>    Imagex /unmount D:\Mount
>
>    10. Using Explorer, copy the C:\Windows\system32\reminst\boot\boot.sdi
>          file to the D:\RemoteInstall\boot
>          folder.
>
> Copy the x86 and x64 boot images
>
> 1. On WDS01, using Explorer, copy any x86 boot image that you want to
>      use to the D:\RemoteInstall\x86\Images
>      folder, name the boot image boot.wim.
>
>    Note: If you just want a boot image to test with you can copy the
>      default Windows PE 3.0 x86 boot image
>      from WAIK. It is named winpe.wim and
>      is locate in the C:\Program
>      Files\Windows AIK\Tools\PETools\x86
>      folder
> 2. Using Explorer, copy any x64 boot image that you want to use to the
>      D:\RemoteInstall\x64\Images folder,
>      name the boot image boot.wim.
>
>    Note: Again, if you just want a boot image to test with, you can copy
>      the default Windows PE 3.0 x64 boot
>      image from WAIK. It is named winpe.wim
>      and is locate in the C:\Program
>      Files\Windows AIK\Tools\PETools\amd64
>      folder
>
> Configure the WDS Providers
>
> 1. On WDS01, using the Registry Editor, configure the WDS Providers
>      order by navigating to the
>      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WDSServer\
>      Providers\ WDSPXE key, and create a
>      new Multi-String Value with the
>      following settings:
>
>    Name: ProvidersOrder
>
>    Data: WDSSIPR
> 2. Using the Registry Editor, configure the TFTP root folder by
>      navigating to the
>      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WDSServer\Providers\
>      WDSTFTP key, and create a new String
>      Value with the following settings:
>
>    Name: RootFolder
>
>    Data: D:\RemoteInstall
>
> Configure the Policies
>
> 1. On WDS01, using Notepad, edit the
>      C:\Windows\system32\wdssipr.dll.conf.ini
>      file. In the IMAGES POLICY section,
>      configure the following values
>
>    X86BootImage=boot\x86\images\boot.wim
>
>    X64BootImage=boot\x64\images\boot.wim
> 2. Save the C:\Windows\system32\wdssipr.dll.conf.ini
>      file.
>
> Additional DHCP and WDS provider
>   configuration
>
> 1. On WDS01, using a Command Prompt, configure the transport server
>      to use DHCP by typing the following
>      command + press Enter.
>
>    WDSUTIL /Set-TransportServer /ObtainIPv4From:DHCP
> 2. Leave the Command Prompt open.
> 3. Using the Command Prompt, configure the DHCP PXEClient option,
>      by typing the following commands +
>      press Enter after each line.
>
>    Netsh
>
>    dhcp
>
>    server \WDS01
>
>    add optiondef 60 PXEClient String 0 comment=”PXE support”
>
>    set optionvalue 60 STRING PXEClient
>
>    exit
> 4. Leave the Command Prompt open.
> 5. Using the Registry Editor, configure the DHCP ports option by
>      navigating to the
>      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WDSServer\Providers\
>      WDSPXE key, and change the
>      UseDhcpPorts data value from 1 to 0.
> 6. Using the Command Prompt, start the WDS transport server by typing the
>      following command + press Enter.
>
>    WDSUTIL /Start-TransportServer
>
> Done! You should now be able to start
>   the boot images over the network,
>   having configured the WDS PXE listener
>   on a standalone server.

Comment: I cleaned your post up to be more respectful of others - the original link was 4 years old, and 4 years ago Server 2008 R2 did not exist, and thus the answer was correct.

Answer (score 4):

http://blogs.dirteam.com/blogs/sanderberkouwer/archive/2007/03/19/wds-without-active-directory.aspx

First hit on google search for "wds without domain". Funny how admins today need serverfault to find people helping them to enter their question into google ;)

To the topic: the answer is NO.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about everybody else but I don't see SF as just a place to ask questions. It's also a repository of information for sysadmins. Therefore, if the question has merit and is not already on the site, I don't see why it shouldn't be asked. Even this question and its answer add value to the site...please correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: Well, yes, but that was really a just "google your question" thing. I never see serverfault as an excuse to be lazy myself. Looking lazy just does not look good.

Comment: the highest voted answer to this meta question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers is to downvote the person making the LMGTFY comment, just sayin.  (also, tone down the insults, please, it 'does not look good')